# Blue-screen error message

Tags: windows-7

Blue Screen problem when I play **[PES2019](https://www.konami.com/wepes/2019/eu/en/)**

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
```

Additional information about the problem:

```
  BCCode:   124
  BCP1: 0000000000000000
  BCP2: FFFFFA8008371028
  BCP3: 00000000B6000000
  BCP4: 0000000000100153
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1
```

Files that help describe the problem:

```
C:\Windows\Minidump\051320-37253-01.dmp
C:\Users\t\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-106813-0.sysdata.xml
```